# oracle CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'-TO_DSINTERVAL

Tags: oracle

In my oracle database, I am setting one date field like this

```
update abc set 
startdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'-TO_DSINTERVAL('0 00:59:00');
```

but when I do

```
select * from abc w where 
w.startdate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'-TO_DSINTERVAL('0 00:59:00');
```

after a few minutes then it does not return this row.

To my surprise

```
select * from abc w where 
w.startdate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'-TO_DSINTERVAL('0 00:59:00');
```

returns this row.

How is it possible?
Please help me understand.

Comment: What data type is `startdate`; and what time zone is the selected value in *or* what time zone is you session in? It looks like there is some implicit conversion happening that you are not expecting or handling.

Comment: the data type of startdate is 'Date'.  There is certainly some implicit conversion happening. The session is in PST. Is there any way we can stop or handle the implicit conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67967403/oracle-current-timestamp-at-time-zone-gmt-to-dsinterval/67967645#comment120132799_67967403)

> the data type of startdate is 'Date'. There is certainly some implicit conversion happening. The session is in PST. Is there any way we can stop or handle the implicit conversion?

`CAST` the right-hand side of the expression to a `DATE` rather than allowing an implicit cast to occur (which would cast the `DATE` value on the left-hand side to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` data type with your current session time zone).

```sql
select *
from   abc
where  startdate < CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'GMT'-TO_DSINTERVAL('0 00:59:00') AS DATE);
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5c3d90df26e3582dfa84d8a64d931219)*

Comment: Just for @Jean's info, the implicit cast is [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-98BE3A78-6E33-4181-B5CB-D96FD9DC1694): "During SELECT FROM operations, Oracle converts the data from the column to the type of the target variable."